# Start CSS-Transition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I read 5 tutorials about how to start a CSS-Transition with JavaScript, but it doesn't work.
I'm using Safari. 
Here's my Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #test{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
        transition: width 3s linear;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        document.getElementById('test').style.width = 200+'px';
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="test">
      </div>

      <button onclick="test()">Los</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [it works if you use the correct vendor prefixes](http://jsfiddle.net/KzEAZ/).

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use vendor prefixes, safari uses webkit so try addind the `-webkit-` prefix.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #test{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
        -webkit-transition: width 3s linear;
        -moz-transition: width 3s linear;
        transition: width 3s linear;
    }
</style>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/nWpsT/)